# Drupal 6 customizing dual module conflict

Tags: drupal-6, permissions, roles, creation

I am using the [auto assign role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) module to assign the role of **editor** to anyone registering via the "create new account" link. This works just fine.

However, users of the **editor** role can create other users of different role types. To do this I am using the [uCreate](http://drupal.org/project/ucreate) module.

The problem is when an editor creates a user, that user also gets the editor role.

I have looked into a number of hooks to programmatically remove the unwanted role but without success. How might I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "editor role" users creates the users by "uCreate module", the hook_user is being called reside in "auto assign role module", This is the problem.

The user_save function from "ucreate module line:299" call the hook_user with "insert" parameter  in "auto assign role.module file", line no 155.

`case 'insert':
      // If this is an administrator creating the account only use auto_assign if
      // allowed by auto_admin_active
      if (arg(0) == 'admin' && _autoassignrole_get_settings('auto_admin_active') == 0) {
        return;
      }`

Here the code check whether it is admin user, If it is not admin then it will assign editor role to that user.

Instead you can create a custom module and implement hook_user and change the role when a user are inserted.For more info please refer [user_save in drupal 6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/6)